# Spring MVC 4.0 application is getting undeployed in WAS9.0.5 after 10 mins of the deployment

Tags: java, spring, websphere

Once application is deployed in server (WebSphere 9.0.5), application is working for sometime, then its getting undeployed automatically. Below is the application log and browser message

**Browser Output**
Error 404: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /home/display

**Log**
[5/19/22 9:21:20:513 PDT] 00000096 ReloadableCla A WSVR0655I: The D:\WebSphere90\AppServer\profiles\server1\installedApps\TestCell12\checkSheetEAR.ear\checkSheetEAR.war\WEB-INF\classes\com\controller\HomeController.class application artifact updated at 0.
[5/19/22 9:21:20:513 PDT] 00000096 ApplicationMg A WSVR0653I: Restarting web module checkSheett.war of application: checkSheetEAR.
[5/19/22 9:21:20:513 PDT] 00000096 ApplicationMg I WSVR0227I: User initiated module stop operation requested on Module, checkSheett.war, of application, checkSheetEAR

Answer (score 1):

WSVR0655I indicates that the server's automatic application reloading mechanism (AKA "hot deployment") detected a change to a file in the app, triggering an app restart. In this case, it claims that the file "updated at 0" - the number there is the lastModified value for the file, so it appears that the file became unreadable for some reason (network hiccup on an networked file system? someone actually moved/deleted/changed permission on the file?).

It's probably worth investigating what caused that failure to access the file, but if you simply don't want transient issues with file visibility to result in the application restarting, you can disable automatic reloading on that application through the server's administrative console. Select the application on the "Applications > Application Types > WebSphere enterprise applications" page, then select "Class loading and update detection". On that page, check the "Override class reloading settings for web and EJB modules" box, and also set the value of "Polling interval for updated files" to "0".

If you need it, documentation for the reloading settings can be found at https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/9.0.5?topic=application-class-loading-update-detection-settings